# Enter new React component after you pass authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, components

So I'm trying to create page where you can see all the info only when you log into your account.
I created authentication system with NodeJS and now I want it so you could only enter certain component (page) when you pass authentication. Maybe someone can suggest some kind of tutorial or give me example how could I do it?

My Login component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
    }
    const onChangePassword= (e) => {
     setPassword(e.target.value);
    }
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        const user = {
            username: username,
            password: password
            };
        e.preventDefault();
        const authentication = axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/login', user);
        if(authentication === true) window.location = '/user';
        else console.log("ERORR")
        
    }
        
    
    return (
        <div className="Login">
           <h2>Traffic scan admin panel</h2>
           <div className="LoginInfo-Logins">
            <form>
                <input type="text"
                required
                className=""
                value={username}
                onChange={onChangeUsername}
                placeholder="Username*" 
                />
                <input type="text"
                required
                className=""
                value={password}
                onChange={onChangePassword}
                placeholder="Password*" 
                /> 
            </form>
           </div>
           <button onClick={onSubmit}>SIGN IN</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Login;
```

My NodeJS part for logging in:

```
router.route('/login').post(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await Users.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    if(!user) throw Error('User do not exist')
    else {
        if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
            console.log('Logged in');
            res.send('Logged in');
        } else throw Error('Password is incorrect')
    }
});
```

Comment: Hope this tutorial helps -  https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-protected-routes-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the react-router to navigate your different pages, then you can use the react hook useHistory to navigate to your dashboard. When you get the response from the server, you would also want to save that you are now logged in.

I would suggest doing this with JWT tokens as they will also have an expiry so you can't use them after X amount of time. [Here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/06/react-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example) is a good link to get you started on how to do this.

Then once you have a token, you would need to configure either your router or other means of displaying content to do so only if you have a valid router. As a side note, make sure that any authenticated actions happen on the server side and not client side. For example it is not okay to GET http://127.0.0.1/login and receive back {token: randomString, isAdmin: true} and then store the isAdmin and use that to do specific things. (Note it's okay to use that for display purposes but not for anything which will enable you to see or modify confidential data, keep that all serverside)

Also of note: I would ensure that putting in a wrong user displays the same error as wrong password (so someone can't come and enumerate for all users on your site). And also suggest that you using something like [Morgan](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/morgan.html) to track the number of login requests over time from a single IP or for a single user and add them to a blacklist so people can't brute force passwords.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
    let history = useHistory();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
    }
    const onChangePassword= (e) => {
     setPassword(e.target.value);
    }
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        const user = {
            username: username,
            password: password
            };
        e.preventDefault();
        const authentication = axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/login', user);
        if(authentication === true) history.push('/home');
        else console.log("ERORR")
        
    }
        
    
    return (
        <div className="Login">
           <h2>Traffic scan admin panel</h2>
           <div className="LoginInfo-Logins">
            <form>
                <input type="text"
                required
                className=""
                value={username}
                onChange={onChangeUsername}
                placeholder="Username*" 
                />
                <input type="text"
                required
                className=""
                value={password}
                onChange={onChangePassword}
                placeholder="Password*" 
                /> 
            </form>
           </div>
           <button onClick={onSubmit}>SIGN IN</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Login;
```